# Jhipster import-jdl "Cannot find module 'glob'"

Tags: jhipster, glob, jdl

I cannot import my file "my-model.jh"

With jhipster 3.12

i do :

yo jhipster:import-jdl my-model.jh

```
enter codemodule.js:327
throw err; Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DEV\jhipster\generator-jhipster\node_modules\shelljs\src\common.js:7:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

So i add to my package.json

```
"glob": "^7.1.1"
```

But i still get the same error

Do you know what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I fix it adding the glob to jhipster generator package.json then re build it